# Read value from registry via batch file without showing the source

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-registry

This batch file works fine:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Lenovo /v DisplayVersion | msg %username%
```

It opens a window with the value, but it also shows the source. 
How can write it without showing the source?

Comment: Do you know about `@echo off`?

Answer (score 0):

Found a method.

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo" /v "DisplayVersion"') do set "value=%%~b"
msg *USERNAME* %value%
exit
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Other readers may find it useful.

Comment: It seems like you could have just added ``exit`` to the batch file you already had.  Otherwise, I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Lenovo /v DisplayVersion ^| find "DisplayVersion"') do @msg *USERNAME* %%a
```

- The @ symbols prevents the command echoing.
- Using `for` command's tokens and delimiter option we split the string by space and get the 3rd value which is actually the value. TO get only that line we use `find`.
- Then we message to the USERNAME about the specific value. The command echoing of this is also turned off.

**Footnotes**

- You can also add `@echo off` at the beginning of batch file to stop more @s.
- If you run this from command prompt instead of batch file, then replace two percent signs (%%) with one (%).